# Date Query with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have fields in my table for date, but they contain everything - day, year and month. Can I write a query to get only the records, which has month equal to the current month? I can do this:

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$month = $today->format('m');

$cat = $em->getRepository('EMBudgetTrackerBundle:Expense')->find(1);   
$ex_date = $cat->getDate();
```

and compare $month and $ex_date, but can I write some kind of query? Something like this:

```
public function getExpensesByMonth($month)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $q->select('e')
      ->where('e.date = :date')
      ->setParameter('date', $month);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: How is your dates formatted in database table? What is the column type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you database column is in DateTime format you can use the DateTime object in your query. As far as I know you can only query for time ranges though.

```
public function getExpensesByMonth($beginning, $end)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $q->select('e')
      ->where('e.date > :beginning')
      ->andWhere('e.date < :end')
      ->setParameter('beginning', $beginning)
      ->setParameter('end', $end);

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```